# как получить числа из строки и суммировать их?

Tags: java

String text = "Вася заработал 5000 рублей, Петя - 7563 рубля, а Маша - 30000 рублей";
как получить сумму их з.п? (42563)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Вася заработал 5000 рублей, Петя - 7563 рубля, а Маша - 30000 рублей";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+"); // регулярное выражение на числа
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        int sum = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()); //конвертируем найденные строки в числа и суммируем их
        }
        System.out.println(sum); //42563
    }
```